# I m experiencing some problems using Gradlew bundleRelease

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

I' m working on this cocos2dx game project, that uses gradle for building for Android in linux.

I can build apks for release of debug without problems using
./gradlew assembleRelease or ./gradlew assebleDebug

But now, I have to build an app bundle in order to upload on google play store.

I tried ./gradlew bundleRelease and it seems the build was ok since I did not get any error message, but a Build Sccessfull message.

Despite that, I was not able to find the aab file that should be generated. I look for the /app/build/outputs/ and there is only the apk folder, not the bundle folder.

Any Ideas ?

Thanks in advance people.

Comment: just curious, are you able to generate bundle using Build->Generate Signed Bundle or APK flow of android studio?

Comment: I did not the test. As far I know, using android studio would be very similar, since it uses gradlew behind the curtins. Am I correct?

Comment: I forget to mention: Gradle version is 6.8